# converting concat'ed number result to corosponding text form db

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code when I type

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM ))
    {

            echo "<table border=1 ; cellpadding:5px; style='border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px #ccc; width: 100%; height:200px'>";
    {

        echo "<tr>
                <td width= 35%> " All Values' </td>
                <td width= 65%>  '.$row[1].'  </td>
                </tr>';
    }

    echo "</table>";

    }

mysql_free_result($result);
```

it displays

```
151,152,154,155
```

Those numbers which is concat to single line, "151,152,154,155" are from the table called validation and table field is ID. There is another field in the validation table called text which corresponds to the number.

Table example

```
**MySQL Table: validation**

ID    text
--------------
151   correct
152   plugin
153   often
154   type
155   apple
```

For example ID=151 row has text, "Correct" and ID=152 row has text, "plugin" and so on...

I want to display like this....

```
 correct, plugin, type, apple
```

instead of numbers.

Please suggest me how to replace the numbers with codes.

I tried of adding

```
 '.$row[1].'
```

to an array and fetching using for loop but cannot get success.

Comment: The HTML structure is wrong, you're mixing some html properties with some css ones. Moreover, you shouldn't use mysql_*, you should use mysqli_* or PDO, since mysql is deprecated.

Comment: I used css inside the table definition. What corrections do you suggest? But my issue is to convert that number into corresponding texts.

Comment: I would rather suggest you to check some basics html, css and php&sql tutorials. Your code shouldn't even work: the sytanx is wrong, the logic is not anymore valid (you shouldn't use the mysql_* prototipe, as said above) and the HTML & CSS structure is wrong too. You should have an idea of what you're doing, from the code above I actually think you haven't really a clue of what you're doing, which is not good.

Comment: My assumption is that you are just beating in the bush. The code works and it displays well and I am sure I know what I am doing :). I just want to know how to convert the number into corresponding text in the field. What php/sql script I need to use to make it happen.

Comment: Assume whatever you want. I can do this kind of stuff, and I'm telling you this is not they way to do that. There is so much wrong in that code that I don't really see why I should give some effort, it is better to rewrite the entire code rather than correcting it, that's why I'm telling you to check the basics first. Your code is full of syntax errors, you're querying in the wrong way, you have some random brackets opening everywhere without any reasons (which is syntax error, anyway), you have no clue of what the "$row" does and your HTML is mixing some html properties with some CSS ones.

Comment: You are not coming to the point. I need solution. I got help writing the code from ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php ). If there was syntax error then it would be in errorlog or it would give me blank page, right? I didnt see any of them and $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM ). $result is a value that is obtained from a sql query. I didnt pasted that query. I am not asking anyone to test me. I am asking for solution to solve it. You are going wrong track :)

Comment: I personally provide solutions to users who show some efforts. Again, you didn't write this code or, if you did, you copied and pasted it from somewhere else and didn't understand what you did.

Comment: I have no interest to prove that I understand the code. I am not just able to get the number converted to text. IF I dont concat then I can display result in text but when I concat I cannot since I am joining tables and they are separated in different tables. Sorry to waste your time.